# Set Linux master volume from Qt application

Tags: linux, qt, audio, volume

I didn't find a way to check and set the master volume at a specific value from a Qt application.

Is this possible using Qt 5.9? Ideally this would be a cross-platform solution.

One solution would be to run a script using a `QProcess`.

My command line would be `amixer set Master 70%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it appears there is no way to do this with `Qt` audio classes, I've used the static [startDetached](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached-1) method of `QProcess` to run my command:

`QProcess::startDetached("amixer set Master 70%")`

It's working fine and is a non-blocking operation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying this way:

```
QProcess *lProc = new QProcess();

lProc->start("amixer set Master 70%");
lProc->waitForFinished();

QString lResult = lProc->readAllStandardOutput();
qDebug() << lResult;
delete lProc;
```